# Do not bind drop down list if selected value not found in list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, dropdown

How do I tell `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AccID") %>'` do not perform the binding if `AccID` is not in the list of items?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceAccount" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetUsableAccountByUser"
    TypeName="t_MT_AccCode" OnSelected="ObjectDataSourceAccount_Selected" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSourceAccount_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="companyCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="departmentCode" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="badgeNumber" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="userRole" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAccount" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceAccount"
    DataTextField="accountDesc" DataValueField="id" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AccID") %>' 
    ondatabinding="DropDownListAccount_DataBinding" 
    ondatabound="DropDownListAccount_DataBound">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This will do it `Bind("AccID") != null ? Bind("AccID") : "[Add Default Value]"` e.g. "0"

Comment: @Prabhat `AccID` is not necessary null, it can be `123` but list of items only have `ABC` and `DEF`. It cause error in this case.

Comment: Null is for handling "_Object reference_" error if "**AccID**" is not present in list of items.

Comment: @Prabhat But my error is `'DropDownListAccount' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items`.

Comment: My bad thanks for clarifying. If that the case then you can use Gridview Rowdatabound event to find DropDownList and search whether AccId is present in list of items. If yes assign same else assign default value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue.

But I was hoping I can solve it through `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AccID") %>'` instead.

```
protected void DropDownListAccount_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropDownListAccount = (DropDownList)sender;
    DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)((GridViewRow)dropDownListAccount.Parent.Parent).DataItem;
    int currentRowDataKeyItemId = int.Parse(currentDataRowView["ID"].ToString());
    int accountId = t_MT_MTItem.GetAccountIdByItemId(currentRowDataKeyItemId);
    dropDownListAccount.SelectedValue = accountId.ToString();
}
```